# Magnific popup how to catch close?

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

This is my magnific popup

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $.magnificPopup.open({
                        items: {
                            src: '#recently-viewed-popup'
                        },
                        type: 'inline'
                    });
                }, <?php echo $time_popup; ?>);
            });
        </script>
```

i catch open, but how to catch when client close it ?

Try with this:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $.magnificPopup.open({
                        items: {
                            src: '#recently-viewed-popup'
                        },
                        type: 'inline'
                    });
                }, <?php echo $time_popup; ?>);
            });
            $.magnificPopup.close({
                alert(55);
            })
        </script>
```

But without effect.

Comment: Read the documentation. Look at the `callbacks.close` option. http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api

Comment: Also I would advise **not** using setInterval and instead use a timeout...

Comment: Ty guys, i will try with callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here u can see example, when u close it alert with **33** will appear:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $.magnificPopup.open({
                        items: {
                            src: '#recently-viewed-popup'
                        },
                        type: 'inline',

                        callbacks: {
                            close: function testt(){
                                alert(33);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }, <?php echo $time_popup; ?>);
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it.